How Can I calculate division in Galois field?
I am studying cryptography especially AES I am stuck at the Galois Field arithmetic. I understand what is the log and anti-log tables and how to use them. But to understand why the arithmetic is that way addition and subtraction are the same (XOR), multiplication(anti-log[(log[a]+log[b])%255]), and division (anti-log[(log[a]+log[b])%255]). I have coded the arithmetic system in Python, But when I got to division it didn't work I used the same formula it didn't give the correct answer I used a=3, b=7 the code gave me 104 and the online calculators gave me 211
def addition(a, b):
    return a ^ b

def subtraction(a, b):
    return a ^ b

def galios_multiplication(a,b):
    product = 0
    iter = 0
    hi_bit = 0
    while iter < 8:
        if (b&1) == 1:
            product ^= a  
        hi_bit = a & 0x80      
        a <<= 1
        if hi_bit == 0x80:
            a ^= 0x11b
        b >>= 1
        iter +=1
    return product


def generate_log_table():
    atable = [0] * 256
    ltable = [0] * 256
    a = 1
    for c in range(255):
        atable[c] = a
        
        hi_bit = a & 0x80
        a <<= 1
        if hi_bit == 0x80:
            a ^= 0x11b
            
        a ^= atable[c]
        
        ltable[atable[c]] = c
        
    atable[255] = atable[0]
    
    ltable[0] = 0
    ltable[1] = 255
    
    return ltable,atable


def fast_galios_mult(a, b):
    ltable,atable = generate_log_table()
    if a == 0 or b == 0:   
        return 0
    else:
        sum_a_b = ltable[a] + ltable[b]
        sum_a_b %= 255
        sum_a_b = atable[sum_a_b]
        ''' Now, we have some fancy code that returns 0 if either
            a or b are zero; we write the code this way so that the
            code will (hopefully) run at a constant speed in order to
            minimize the risk of timing attacks
        '''
    return sum_a_b
    
    
def galois_multiplicative_inverse(a):
    ltable,atable = generate_log_table()
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return atable[(255-ltable[a])]
    
def modified_divison(a,b):
    if b == 0:
        raise ValueError("Division by zero is undefined in GF(2^8)")
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    b = galois_multiplicative_inverse(b)
    return fast_galios_mult(a,b)
    
    
def galios_division(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        raise ValueError("Division by zero is undefined in GF(2^8)")
    if a == 0:
        return 0
    b = galois_multiplicative_inverse(b)
    return fast_galios_mult(a,b)
    
    
   
print("Galois normal mult: ",galios_multiplication(7, 211))
print("Galois Fast mult: ",fast_galios_mult(7,211))
print("Galois division: ",galios_division(3,7))
print("Galois modified division: ",modified_divison(3,7))


            
            
``` 


$104_2=x^6+x^5+x^3$ is correct because
$$7_2\cdot104_2=(x^2+x+1)(x^6+x^5+x^3)=x^8+x^4+x3\equiv x+1\pmod{x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1},$$
where $x^8+x^4+x^3+x+1=11b_{16}$ is the defining polynomial.  Of course, $x+1=3_2$, so
$$7_2\cdot 104_2=3_2$$ implying the claim $3/7=104$. May be whatever on-line calculator you found is using different notation?

generate_log_table() should only be done once, outside of fast_galios_mult(). Jyrki Lahtonen already answered you question. If timing attacks are an issue, then instead of using log tables and checking for a or b = 0, use a 64KB multiply table:  table[a*256+b]= galiois_multiplication(a,b).

OMG! I did not notice that you are regenerating the LUTs on every call. A massive waste of cycles, surely.
